# One column in HTML table to have no horizontal border lines

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to style the following table but I can't avoid styling every single cell. There should be a single border line between all the cells except for the cells from e.g. 4th column. In addition I am trying to get both parts of the table zebra striped (it isn't shown in the layout below).

```
┌───┬───┬───┐    ┌───┬───┬───┐
├───┼───┼───┤    ├───┼───┼───┤
├───┼───┼───┤    ├───┼───┼───┤
├───┼───┼───┤    ├───┼───┼───┤
├───┼───┼───┤    ├───┼───┼───┤
├───┼───┼───┤    ├───┼───┼───┤
├───┼───┼───┤    ├───┼───┼───┤
├───┼───┼───┤    ├───┼───┼───┤
└───┴───┴───┘    └───┴───┴───┘
```

What would be the most effective way to do it?

**Update.** I accepted Jaime's answer and modified suggested code a bit:

```
<style>
.tbl            { border-collapse:collapse; }
.tbl tr         { background-color: red; }
.tbl tr.stripe  { background-color: green; }
.tbl td         { border:solid 1px black; }
.tbl td.none    { border-style:none; background-color: white; }
</style>

<table class="tbl">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td class="none">4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr class="stripe">
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td class="none">4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Not sure it is correct to explicitely set td.none background as white but I don't know if it's possible to specify that the element's background should be the same as the page's background.

Comment: it looks like two tables, maybe you should just create two tables

Comment: You may get somewhere with the `col` and `colgroup` HTML tags within your table, and style based on those. I'd test and actually answer but don't have the time now.

Comment: @Luke - two tables won't do because when the table is resized the text in e.g. the first row of the left table can take 3 lines and the text in the first row of the right table - 1 line, so the rows won't be in line.

Comment: @Stephen P - I spent a few hours playing with `col` but I couldn't make it work. I am trying to get both parts of the table zebra striped and I was able to do it only syling every single cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
<style>

.tbl {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.tbl td {
    border:solid 1px red;
}

.tbl td.none {
    border-style:none;
}

</style>
```

with html:

```
<table class="tbl">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td class="none">4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>7</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know your HTML markup, I don't know if you set individual `id`s for your `<TR>`'s or if you keep a common `class` attribute, which would let you do something like Jaime suggested.

If not, and you already depend on jQuery, you might like something like this (if I understand you correctly):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        table { border-collapse: collapse; }
        td { border: solid grey 1px; }
        td.none { border: none; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </table>
        <script>$("td:nth-child(4)").addClass("none");</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would forego borders on 4th column. If you need to do it for every fourth column, change `td:nth-child(4)` to `td:nth-child(4n)`.

Comment: Thanks, pal, but I'm not using jquery. Should probably start learning it. As I understand, your answer won't work without jquery?

Comment: Indeed it will not, and using jQuery simply for this thing is most likely overkill. As DA points out, it's available in pure CSS, but browser support is so-so (IE9+, FF3.5+, Safari 3+). For a publicly facing web, I wouldn't count on it in pure CSS.

Answer (score 1):

CSS 3 will do it:

```
td:nth-child(4) {
   ...styles that will apply to the fourth TD...
}
```

Comment: I'd be glad to use your answer, DA, but it doesn't seem to work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Column groups http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#colgroups might help you achieve what you need, because you can specify the styling for specific columns. 
An example is provided here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#sample

Comment: It seems however that column groups can't help with this particular requirement - I checked it before posting the question.